# Find the surface area of the part of the hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: calculus

Find the surface area of the part of the hyperbolic paraboloid $z = xy$ which lies inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and in the positive octant $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$.

Attempt:

$$g(x,y)=xy$$

$$g_x = y, g_y = x$$

$$\int \int \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} dA = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+r^2}rdrd\theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the answer with the second integral formula.
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+r^2}rdrd\theta &=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[{1\over3}\left(1+r^2\right)^{3/2}\right]_{0}^{1}d\theta\\\\ &=
\frac{\pi}{2} \left[\frac{2\sqrt{2} - 1}{3}\right] \\\\&=
\frac{\pi\left(2\sqrt{2} - 1\right)}{6}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I shouldve been specific in the question. I know how to solve the integral just wanted to know if the set up was ok. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but for the people that see this in the future. The bounds should be different for $\theta$.

since $x^2+y^2=1$ gives an equation for a circle, the bounds for $\theta$ should be $0\leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi$ Everything else looks fine.